# MVVM - Using simple model as it's own view model is a bad practice?

Tags: mvvm, dry

Guess we have simple **model**, e.g. let it be a ***Person***  { Name, Age }.

Now we want to display a list of persons.

- Persons are read-only
- We don't need to edit them
- We don't need any additional stuff like presentation properties, etc.

Now question is if it is a good practice do not create ***PersonViewModel*** class that will probably be a copy of model class or will delegate all its properties? Is it a good idea to simply bind listbox to list of persons, not to their view models? It looks DRY enough, but what about idea of MVVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no issue with bypassing the VM and using the M directly in the View. Sometimes the models are so small and static that loading them into a wrapping VM is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I've created standalone ViewModels, but generally not standalone models.  The reason for this is DataBinding -- most POCOs don't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and adding them in to make them pseudo-Models seems to defeat the purpose of re-using a simple class AND respecting the MVVM pattern.

Now, if you KNOW you're never going to be editing them, it may not be a bad idea.  A VM with simple property redirects seems a bit pointless to me.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't written that models are read-only so we don't need INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. [Edited question]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then it becomes a ViewModel, and you can bind to it.  :)  When I wrote [SoapBox Core](http://soapboxcore.com) which is all MVVM, I took the approach that everything is a ViewModel.  The only Model objects were classes from third party libraries that I brought in and wrapped in a ViewModel of my own.

Comment: Getting to the OP's question, though, *why* did you do it this way?  For very simple Model objects that are only ever displayed as read only, why did you go that extra step to creating a ViewModel for them?  I don't think this is bad or good, just that the OP is trying to find out *why* someone would do this or why it's bad not to.

Comment: @Anderson Imes: In the specific case of an immutable object (readonly) there's no reason you'd implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so binding to it is fine.  Or if you don't expect it to change, I don't see a reason not to bind to it.

Comment: Originally it sounded like you went "all" viewmodel... this would be a complete reinvention of all Model objects as viewmodels, but your clarification seems to indicate you took it on a case-by-case basis.  This is much clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t create a ViewModel for the Person business object when the ViewModel doesn’t introduce new required functionality.

You might be interested that there is a second approach in the MVVM community: Create a ViewModel per View and not per Business Object.

Sample applications that follow this approach can be found on the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) website.